# When playing the animation in compositing some render layers are disabled or switched

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, viewlayers

I'm quite new to compositing in blender and wanted to start comping an animation I created. I've plugged all the different passes to get my beauty layer for each view layer. When I'm on the first frame everything seems fine:

[image]

zoom in on the plants for instance:
[image]

viewer result:
[image]

But when I play the animation and stop on a random frame, some layers get disabled or switch to another render layer, which doesn't make sense, and I have no idea why. I've looked everywhere checked so many tutorials but nothing covers this issue.

here I'm at frame 42, the view layer "plants" just got disabled :
[image]

viewer result: [image]

I really have no idea what is causing this, and I'm thinking that if this happens while comping, I'm pretty sure that when I render I will have the same issue. I would be so grateful if someone could help me out with this!

Comment: It sounds like a bug ... could be a reason you use blender with [Real-time Compositor](https://code.blender.org/2022/07/real-time-compositor/) feature?

Comment: I haven't activated the feature, so I don't think the issue comes from that. Could it be something with my view layers? I'm wondering if I don't have data in my openEXR files from different viewlayers maybe

Comment: Pink color indicates missing data ... you already see missing name (for some reason) it never happened to me ... also we don't know how EXR was generated and saved, but if it works in one frame should be same in all others. You can try to share working frame and frame with issue to let as check how does it behave in our machines. Frame 42 is always like that or is it randomly per play? Are Layers still listed at frame (file) 42? Did you render sequence at one run or you re-rendered some frames?

Comment: thanks for getting back! The layers go missing randomly per play, the layers are still listed, they just get unchecked, so I would have to manually reselect the layer in order to see it in the viewer result, and when I go back to frame 1, I have the issue in frame 1 too, so I have to reselect the layers in order to see them. I've done render sequence in one run, but, I rendered single layer each time instead of rendering all layers in one go

Comment: I assume EXR file is rendered by blender ... since it is impossible to create an EXR in blender without ViewLayer (to set empty field for view layer name) it seems to be a bug, but I can't reproduce your issue in my setup https://we.tl/t-1Sry7cHE3k. so try some simpler scene, try Defaults > Load Fabric Settings (if it is not some setup or addon conflict) or try different blender version (official release in the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here :) I will test a render to see if in the final render the issue appears, maybe it's a display bug from Blender, could that be? I can't really share the file because there are 7 different viewlayers, each 200 frames, so a bit too heavy to share. I checked your file and indeed, it works fine on my side as well. So maybe I did something wrong while rendering the view layers, not sure

Comment: I was writing previous comment without seeing your last one :) Why did you render only one viewlayer? They can be stored in a single EXR. If does it happen randomly it is more some cache issue, than file issue, but disappearing selected layer looks like file issue for contrary :) Can you share few frames of some layer? If issue will considered as a bug expect closing your Q (bugs are not allowed here) also we are here to close by automatically moved to chat room (chatting also not allowed here :) BTW if you overexpose your last screen, plants seems to be there https://imgur.com/rHKWDgZ

Comment: First time user, so didn't know bugs and chatting is not allowed! I've shared 10 frames per layer here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11iywVriCcapMFqVRdTyUNxLIL3LrvKoo but, will only be uploaded in 40 minutes! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: OK I'm going for jogging, I will check your files later (or someone) ... just be sure you set your shared files as public (so people can access file without asking special permission).

Comment: all set to public! thanks again!

Comment: I can't open cave_comp.blend - "Missing DNA block", but that isn't the issue. Also cave_exr folder is missing frame 8, 9 ... I'm noting that so you can ensure your sequence is complete (probably some upload issue or humanity :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139721/discussion-between-vklidu-and-justine-hoeck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plants** - frame 1 appears fine, frame 2 and others are pink - blender says - "Can't load image" ... due unassigned Viewlayer I guess.

---

### Issue

Your Viewlayer list is not consistent for whole image sequence. Almost all sequences contains one layer more at frame one.

It seems like blender is not looking for a viewlayer name, but is using position index.
Let's say at sequence *Plants* ...

**Frame 1**

- 1 Composite
- 2 lantern
- 3 plants

**Frame 2-10**

- 1 Composite
- 2 plants

When you set *plants* at frame 1 that is under position 3 and move to frame 2, blender can't find position 3. Name field in node became empty and blender is notifying you "Can't load image".

When you are at frame 2 and try to fix it by assigning view layer to *plants*, that is on position 2, than moving to frame 1 appears layer *lantern* because it is on position 2 at that frame.

... if I don't use frame 1 viewlayer stay assigned to plants and all is fine for me.

If you don't know how to solve the issue by your self with knowing this - please share your source file (used to generate EXR). You can delete all objects just keep one (can be a cube) in each Viewlayer.

Comment: So basically I should remove frame 1 from the sequence and then it should work fine?

Comment: So i removed frame 1 from the image sequence and it works! Thanks so much for looking into this :) I'm not sure why there are more layers in frame 1 compared to the other frames, but removing it did the trick! Thanks again!!

Comment: Great it works for you :) You'r welcomed.